# Codigniter: Display current user in homepage after log-in

Tags: php, codeigniter

I want to ask how can I display the current user that has logged-in in my homepage.

Here is my login view:

```
<form action="login2" method="POST" id="log_form" name="log_form" style="margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;"> 
                        <div class="modal-body">
                           <div class="container">     
                              <div id="nav_log1">
                                Username: <input type="text" id="txt_user1" name="txt_user1" style="color: black;"/>
                                Password: <input type="password" id="txt_pass1" name="txt_pass1" style="color: black;"/>
                              </div>
                            </div> <!-- /container -->
                        <div class="modal-footer" style="padding: 20px; margin-top: 20px;">
                            <button type="submit" value="login" id="btn_login" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" name="btn_login">Sign-In</button>
                            <button class="btn btn-warning btn-sm" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
                        </div>
                        </div>
                     </form>
```

Here is my model:

```
public function select_login($value2){
    $login_user = $this->db->select('*')
                           ->from('tblusers')
                           ->where('Username', $value2['txt_user1'])
                           ->where('Password', $value2['txt_pass1'])
                           ->get()->row();
           return $login_user;
}
```

And here is the controller that corresponds to the action of my form in my view:

```
 public function login2(){
    $data = array();
    if(!empty($_POST['btn_login'])){

        $session_login = $this->inventory_model->select_login($this->input->post());
        if($session_login){
            $this->session->set_userdata('login_session', array('Username' => $session_login->Username,
                                                                'Password' => $session_login->Password,
                                                                'UserType' => $session_login->UserType));
                                                            redirect('inventorysys_controller/homepage');
        }
        else{
            $this->session->set_flashdata('msg','Invalid Username/Password!');
            redirect('inventorysys_controller/loginpage2');
        }
    }
}
```

As you can see there is a `redirect('inventorysys_controller/homepage');` in my login2 controller. There are two views on that page since I am loading multiple views on my webpage. I will only post the header view since that's where I want to put the name of the user that has logged-in. Here is the view:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="masthead">
    <h3 class="text-muted">Inventory System</h3>&nbsp;
    <ul class="nav navbar-default nav-justified">
      <li><a href="<?php echo site_url('inventorysys_controller/homepage'); ?>">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="<?php echo site_url('inventorysys_controller/inventory'); ?>">Inventory</a></li>
      <li><a href="<?php echo site_url('inventorysys_controller/userslist1'); ?>">Users List</a></li>
      <li><a href="<?php echo site_url('inventorysys_controller/view_employees'); ?>">Employee</a></li>
      <li class="dropdown"><a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" id="dropdownMenu1" data-toggle="dropdown">Administration<span class="caret"></span></a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu1">
            <li role="presentation"><a role="menutitem" tab-index="-1" href="<?php echo site_url('inventorysys_controller/maintenance'); ?>">Inventory Maintenance</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li><a href="<?php echo site_url('inventorysys_controller/about') ?>">About</a></li>
      <li><a name="btn_logsouts" id="btn_logsouts" href="<?php echo site_url('inventorysys_controller/logsouts') ?>"><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-off'></span>&nbsp;Logout</a></li>
    </ul>
 </div>
```

Here is a print screen of my homepage view for you to get my question:

[image]

So that's it, I just want to select the username that has logged-in and show it on my homepage. I know I will create another query like `SELECT * FROM 'tblusers' where 'user' = --blank--`. I just don't know how to deal with that yet. Please help me guys! Thank you in advance for your help! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As i see you are assigning your username in sessions ,you can access it wherever in your code like this.

```
echo $this->session->userdata('Username');
```

Let me know if you have any doubts.

Regards,
Zeeshan.

Comment: Ow, I see, so can I put it in a label in my view like this? <label><?php echo $this->session->userdata('Username); ?></label>

Comment: Yes,anything can be used for styling.Instead of value just replace it with your username.

If it helps you and solve your issue,mark it as answer to help others.

Answer (score 0):

So I solved it thanks to @Zeeshan.

I just added this code in my View:

```
<?php $session_login = $this->session->userdata('login_session'); ?>

<label><?php echo $session_login['Username']; ?></label>
```

I hope this could help you guys. Thank to @Zeeshan!